# CSS Fixed Header, scrolling body with left sidbar/content/right sidbar and footer

Tags: html, css

I have spent the last week trying to tweak a layout and keep rebuilding from scratch without success, so asking for help.

I'm trying to achieve 
 1. a fixed header which does not scroll and always viewable
 2. a main area    with left sidebar (nav) / content / right sidebar (ads) which scroll
 3. a footer which is only visible when scrolled to the bottom

My vision is :

```
|--------------------------------|
| header (always viewable )      |
|--------------------------------|
||  L  |                  |  R  ||
||  e  |                  |  i  ||
||  f  |                  |  g  ||
||  t  |                  |  h  ||
||     |                  |  t  ||
||  S  |   Content Area   |     || 
||  i  |                  |  S  || 
||  d  |                  |  i  ||
||  e  |                  |  d  ||
||  b  |                  |  e  ||
||  a  |                  |  b  ||
||  r  |                  |  a  ||
||     |                  |  r  ||
||------------------------------||
|| footer visible at end scroll ||
||------------------------------||
```

The basic structure of the HTML has a few more divs than could be done with but I'm planning for maximum flexibility ( and problably creating problems)

```
<div class="site-container">

  <div class="site-header">
    SITE HEADER
    <!-- HEADER CONTENT GOES HERE -->
  </div> <!-- site-header -->

  <div class="site-content">
    SITE-CONTENT (with reduced padding not visible )

    <div class="content-main">

      <div class="content-main-left">
        CONTENT-MAIN-LEFT ( Navigation )
      </div>

      <div class="content-main-middle">
        CONTENT-MAIN
        <!-- MIDDLE COLUMN CONTENT GOES HERE -->
        Lorem ipsum dolor etc ...
      </div>

      <div class="content-main-right">
        CONTENT-MAIN-RIGHT ( Ads )
      </div>

      <div class="content-footer">
        CONTENT-FOOTER
      </div>

    </div>    <!-- content-main -->

  </div>      <!-- site-content -->

</div>    <!-- site-container -->
```

However, the more I play with it, the more messy and unworkable it gets.
I'm currently stuck in the loop of fixing one problem while creating another.

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvmo3oa3/) version

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `overflow: scroll`. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to work out how you want that central column of text to work.
If you have a fixed width container, you could **float** the elements, and give them a fixed width.

Many grid systems like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [Base](http://base.gs/) use floated columns to lay things out. They also use media queries in CSS to cater for different screen sizes.

If you want a layout that has fixed-width columns and a variable width central column, and you did want to do things yourself, you can **position things absolutely** inside your main content holder.

Check out an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvmo3oa3/3/) to see how you could use **position:absolute** to lay things out.

There's a few updates to your HTML in there, but a CSS layout like this:

```
   .site-header {
      position: fixed;
      top:0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      padding:20px 0;
      z-index:2;
    }

    .content-main-left {
      width:100px;
      min-height:200px;
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      background-color: tan;
    }

    .content-main {
      padding:0 120px 0 120px; /* padding to make room for the left and rigth columns */
    }

    .content-main-right {
      width:100px;
      min-height:200px;
      position:absolute;
      right:0;
      top:0;
      background-color: rosybrown;
    }

    .site-content {
      position:relative;
      top:120px;
    }

    .content-footer {
      position: relative;
      left:0;
      height: 60px;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

It's always good to strip things back and get one thing working at a time. There were a few lines in that probably weren't helping:

- The left column `<div>` wasn't closed, so your main content was sitting inside that `<div>`
- It looks like you've tried to close the 'site-header' tag at the bottom of the content.
- Putting a `<div>` around your left, center and right columns will help you place a footer at the bottom of all three sections. I've renamed this "site-footer"

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the time spent providing a solution, apologies for the late response.
I really really like your solution, it is very elegant, particularly the scrolling from below the header section.

Answer (score 0):

I found, that if my left / right sidebars grow in length then the bottom of the page starts to get messy.
i.e. [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2cjgtxu1/)
I spent a lot of time playing around but couldn't get it working.

I did not know about the calc option, which I think enables me to have an easier to manage (for a CSS noob like me) solution as I can stay away from absolute positioning.
The result is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnqox3p3/).
I'd love the option of getting the left/right bars to grow to the bottom using something like 
`height: calc(100% - 100);` 
but it doesn't seem to work, and presumably I'd have to delve back into the world of absolute to get it to work.

Again, thanks for the help.